# IsolatedStorageSetting no Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Estou acostumado a usar para Windows Phone, assim:

```
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
public void putString(string key, string variable)
{
    IsolatedStorageSettings iso = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    if (iso.Contains(key)) //Apenas atualiza os valores das chaves
    {
        iso[key] = variable;
    }
    else //Cria novas chaves
    {
        iso.Add(key, variable);
    }
    iso.Save(); 
}

public void getString(TextBox text, string save)
{
    IsolatedStorageSettings iso = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    if (iso.TryGetValue<string>(text.Name, out save))
        text.Text = save;
}
```

Para gravar um valor e pegar o valor, respectivamente, mas no Windows Forms não há o `IsolatedStorageSettings` qual é o método mais fácil de gravar dados no Windows Forms? Pode ser só String mesmo, tudo que encontrei foi via manipulação de arquivos, que é mais complicado.

Há algum método parecido com o que coloquei acima? Usado para gravar uma espécie de dicionário, com chave e valor, pois seria mais rápido e com custo menor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É em arquivo mesmo. Tem a possibilidade de usar o registro do Windows mas não aconselho.

O que você pode fazer para facilitar é usar algo pronto. Eu não gosto destas soluções prontas mas eu sei que atende o que a maioria precisa. Uma destas soluções é usar o [`ApplicationSettings`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) (tem um exemplo usando).

[Tutorial ensinando como usar](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-application-settings-dotnet?view=vs-2015&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Informações mais detalhadas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/application-settings-architecture?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&viewFallbackFrom=netdesktop-5.0).

A classe [`ConfigurationMamager`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) também pode ser uma opção. É menos flexível mas pode resolver o que precisa.

Todo *namespace* [`System.Configuration`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) é dedicado a isto.

Existem bibliotecas de terceiros mas só deveria ir atrás delas se estas não atenderem.

Comment: O que achei mais interessante foi usar `Properties.Settings.Default` porém não estou conseguindo rs, a IDE não deixa o programa rodar com ele, fala para verificar se é nulo antes de salvar um valor, usando assim: `Properties.Settings.Default["key"] = "value";`

Comment: "a IDE não deixa o programa rodar com ele, fala para verificar" é algo muito genérico. Dá algum erro? Dê mais detalhes. Se bem que talvez aí já seja um problema mais específico.

Comment: Não há erro nenhum é a única coisa que aparece